# SWR: verb for what a policy aims to do

Tags: single-word-requests

The sentence is:

> This policy ________ against insider trading and market manipulation.

I want to say, "protects" but that sounds too generic. I'd like something more lofty sounding, ideally anyway.

If needed you may omit against.

Comment: does the policy provide precedures you must follow to make insider trading really difficult, does it simply say "you must not do insider trading"

Comment: What do you mean by "lofty sounding"?

Answer (score 1):

This policy **militates against** insider trading and market manipulation.

> *militate against* [formal]: to make (something) unlikely to happen : to prevent (something) from happening
>
> - *His inexperience militates against his getting an early promotion.*
> - *factors militating against success*

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/militate%20against#:%7E:text=formal,factors%20militating%20against%20success)]

Answer (score 0):

To say that the policy "deters" insider trading might have the more formal tone you are looking for. "Indemnifies [the company]" has a loftier sound but a specific legal denotation which might not be exactly what you intend.

"Safeguards [against]," "insures [against]," "inhibits," "prevents," "impedes," or "thwarts" are some other possibilities.

Comment: Note that some of those verbs include the "against" meaning, so that word should be removed. E.g. you wouldn't say "impedes against".

Comment: Most of those options would not use "against," really. I've updated the answer to clarify the two that would.

Answer (score 0):

Policies **penalize** non-compliance.

Policies are set with the hope of preventing or discouraging certain actions through the expectations that participants wish to avoid the consequences of being caught in violation.

> This policy **penalizes** insider trading and market manipulation.

The policy may (or may not) prove to be an effective deterrent.

From [MW: penalize](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/penalize)

> to punish someone for breaking a rule:
> *He was penalized early in the game for uunsportsmanlike conduct.*